# Query that return a customer with at least one account of each type

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing this question about SQL: Write a query that return Customer ID, types, account numbers and balances of chequing (type chq) and savings (type sav) accounts owned by customers who own at least one chequing account and at least one savings account, order by customer ID, then type, then account number.

Here is the schema:

```
Account = {accNumber, type, balance, branchNumberBranch}
Owns = {customerIDCustomer, accNumberAccount}
Transactions = {transNumber, accNumberAccount, amount}
Employee = {sin, firstName, lastName, salary, branchNumberBranch}
Branch = {branchNumber, branchName, managerSINEmployee, budget}
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
FROM Customer C1, Owns O1, Account A1
WHERE C1.customerID = O1.customerID AND O1.accNumber = A1.accNumber
AND A1.type = 'chq' 
UNION
SELECT C2.customerID, A2.type, A2.accNumber, A2.balance
FROM Customer C2, Owns O2, Account A2
WHERE C2.customerID = O2.customerID AND O2.accNumber = A2.accNumber
AND A2.type = 'sav' 
ORDER BY customerID, type, accNumber
```

but when I use UNION, the query just return customer with both type account but not at least 1 account of each type.

Example output:

```
customerID  type accNumber   balance
----------- ---- ----------- ---------------------------------------
10839       CHQ  15          78226.03
10839       CHQ  296         65875.84
```

This customer has 2 account but both are CHQ type.

I also tried INTERSECT but one account cannot be both type at the same time. What do I do in this case?

Comment: *`.. FROM Customer C2, Owns O2, Account A2 ..`* - do not use comma-style joining, use explicit JOINs.

Comment: @Akina do you mean ```FROM Customer C JOIN Owns O ON C.customerID = O.customerID JOIN Account A on A.accNumber = O.accNumber JOIN Branch B ON B.branchNumber = A.branchNumber?```

Comment: Yes, this SQL text form makes joining conditions clearly visible.

Answer (score 0):

> return Customer ID .. owned by customers who own at least one chequing account and at least one savings account

```sql
SELECT customer.customer_id, ...
FROM customer JOIN account ...
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
HAVING SUM(account.type = 'chequing')
   AND SUM(account.type = 'savings')
```

or

```sql
SELECT customer.customer_id, ...
FROM customer JOIN account ...
WHERE account.type IN ('chequing', 'savings') ...
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT account.type) = 2
```